# Print every loop, not just the final answer

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I want the program to print change the innerHTML of th id "resposta" every time a loop runs. But its just changing the value when the loop ends. I want the page to change the content of the div every second.

I have this code:

```
            <script>
            function sleep(milliseconds) {
              var start = new Date().getTime();
              for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
                if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                  break;
                }
              }
            }

            function escrever(){
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
                var resp = "Executando " + i;
                document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = resp;
                sleep(1000);

            }
             document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML +=  "<br> fim";
            }

            </script>
```

Comment: so you want like `Executando 1 Executando 2....` and so on. and why are you using sleep?

Comment: The id will show "Execuntando 1". After 1 second I want it to change to "Executando 2", after 1 more second it change to "Executando 3" ... ultil the end.

Comment: You have to give browser the time to render the changes. Currently the script reserves the thread, and rending can't happen. Please get familiar with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)/[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) to delay an execution of a function instead of for loops

```js
function escrever(count){
    var ele = document.getElementById("resposta");
    if(count > 10){
        ele.innerHTML +=  "<br> fim";
        return;
    }
    ele.innerHTML = "Executando " + count;
    setTimeout(escrever.bind(null,++count),1000);
}

escrever(1);
```

```html
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()`:

```js
var timeout;
function sleepME(i){
    if(i <= 10){
        timeout = setTimeout((function(){
            var resp = "Executando " + i;
            document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = resp;
            sleepME(++i);
        }), 1000);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML +=  "<br> fim";
        clearTimeout(timeout);   
    }
}
sleepME(1);
```

```html
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

Comment: The id will show "Execuntando 1". After 1 second I want it to change to "Executando 2", after 1 more second it change to "Executando 3" ... ultil the end. This answer will give me all texts together.

Comment: modified my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use setInterval like bellow

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var resp = "Executando " + i++;
    document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML = resp;
    if(i>=10){
        document.getElementById("resposta").innerHTML += "<br> fim";
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
},1000);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/L6q58tf9/23/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=0;  
    interval =  setInterval(function() {   
     if(count<10){
    $("#resposta").html('test'+count);
     } else {
         clearInterval(interval); 
         }
     count ++;
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```